# When Thunderbird Vulnerability Updates will be available for Version 52.9.1 in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: updates, thunderbird, vulnerability

I have Thunderbird version 52.9.1 (64-bit) installed in Ubuntu 16.04.4 LTS.

As Thunderbird version 52.9.1 has multiple vulnerabilities (CVE 2018 5156, CVE 2018 5187, CVE 2018 12371, CVE 2018 12361, CVE 2018 12367), when will updates for Thunderbird will be rolled-out from Ubuntu repository.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you don't want to wait, you can use the Thunderbird PPA by using the command: "sudo add-apt-repository ppa:mozillateam/thunderbird-next". However, this PPA includes beta versions of Thunderbird, so use at your own risk.

Answer (score 0):

Below is some information about mentioned CVEs from Ubuntu Security pages:

- [CVE-2018-5156](https://people.canonical.com/~ubuntu-security/cve/2018/CVE-2018-5156.html) is not related to Thunderbird, fixed in `firefox` package;
- [CVE-2018-5187](https://people.canonical.com/~ubuntu-security/cve/2018/CVE-2018-5187.html) is not related to Thunderbird, fixed in `firefox` package;
- [CVE-2018-12371](https://people.canonical.com/~ubuntu-security/cve/2018/CVE-2018-12371.html) is not related to Thunderbird, fixed in `firefox` package;
- [CVE-2018-12361](https://people.canonical.com/~ubuntu-security/cve/2018/CVE-2018-12361.html) is not related to Thunderbird, fixed in `firefox` package;
- [CVE-2018-12367](https://people.canonical.com/~ubuntu-security/cve/2018/CVE-2018-12367.html) is not related to Thunderbird, fixed in `firefox` package.

Also FYI thunderbird is already at [52.9.1+build3-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 version in 16.04 LTS](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/thunderbird/1:52.9.1+build3-0ubuntu0.16.04.1).

---

If you really sure that listed CVEs are not fixed in 52.9.1 you can use thunderbird from [UbuntuZilla](https://sourceforge.net/p/ubuntuzilla/wiki/Main_Page/) repository - it has 60 version:

```
cat <<EOF | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mozilla.list
deb http://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/ubuntuzilla/mozilla/apt all main
EOF

sudo apt-key adv --recv-keys --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com 2667CA5C
sudo apt-get install thunderbird-mozilla-build
```

or use 
Official PPA for Thunderbird Beta ([ppa:mozillateam/thunderbird-next](https://launchpad.net/~mozillateam/+archive/ubuntu/thunderbird-next)) - it has version 57 dated 2017-11-19:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:mozillateam/thunderbird-next
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```